# How to obtain the list of uncommon tuple present in two list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, intersection

I have two list l1 and l2 which contains tuples inside, I need to filter out the tuple in l1 with the tuple present in l2. How to do this?

```
l1=[('a','b','c','d','e'),('t','y','u','i','o'),('q','s','a','e','r'),('t','f','e','w','l')]
l2=[('a','r'),('l','f')]
output=[('a','b','c','d','e'),('t','y','u','i','o')]


k=0
p=0
filter=[]
for i in l1:
    for j in l2:
        if i[k]!=j[p]:
            ss=i
            filter.append(ss)
            k+=1
            p+=1
```

Comment: Cold you be more clear about the filtering process? I'm not sure how you got those outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more efficient to convert `l2` into a list of sets first so that you can perform subset checks in linear time:

```
s2 = list(map(set, l2))
output = [l for l in l1 if not any(s.issubset(l) for s in s2)]
```

`output` becomes:

```
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), ('t', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o')]
```